# ValueError: The given username must be set (Django)

Tags: python, django

I am Trying to Implement a User Authentication in Django,
But i everytime i try to run the server i am getting this error "ValueError: The given username must be set "
The error message highlights the necessity of setting a specific username. Despite dedicated attempts, a satisfactory resolution to this predicament remains elusive. Regrettably, exhaustive troubleshooting and investigation have yet to yield a viable solution.
Here is Code:

***Signup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Signup</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #222;
            color: #fff;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background-color: #333;
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        input[type="text"],
        input[type="email"],
        input[type="password"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: #444;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: #fff;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #f44336;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #e53935;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            color: #888;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form method="post" action="home/">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def signup(request):
    username=request.POST.get('username')
    email=request.POST.get('email')
    password=request.POST.get('password')
    confirm_password=request.POST.get('confirm_password')
    the_user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
    the_user.save()
    return render(request,'signup.html')

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Login Successfull')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please inspect if the username variable is empty:

```py
def signup(request):
    print(request.POST)
    username=request.POST.get('username')
```

Check the body of the request to see what is actually being sent to your server.
With this, you should see if the username is empty or not.
If the username is empty it means that there is something wrong with your form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to extend UserCreationForm. Here is an example:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-extra-fields

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First your form has an `action="home/"` which is where the form info is being sent to.  Second, when a user goes to the `signup` view to fill out the form you get the error because the form has not been filled out yet!  You need to check this first.

**Solution**

First check if the user is sending the form as opposed to just going to the url to fill it out:

```py
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        email=request.POST.get('email')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        confirm_password=request.POST.get('confirm_password')
        the_user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password)
        the_user.save()
    return render(request,'signup.html')
```

Second, either use Django urls for your action, or just leave the action out of the form.  This will send the form back to the view that created the page:

```html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

Finally, user creation and authentication is a common thing that there are wonderful ready made libraries for it including [Django's own user authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/) (although this will not help with user creation, just authentication), or better yet use [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).